# ¿Como puedo consumir un webservices soap en codeigniter?

Tags: php, webservice, codeigniter, soap

disculpen la poca información en mi pregunta, lo que sucede es que he buscado por toda internet y no he encontrado la solución mas acorde, tengo un api hecha en codeigniter y necesito saber como se hace para consumir un webservices SOAP en este framework. Si alguien sabe por favor necesito ayuda, soy desarrollador full stack pero normalmente siempre trabajo con servicios REST y esta vez me toco un SOAP en codeigniter y estoy algo complicado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura del xml del servicio, como no he trabajado tanto con SOAP, no se mucho de los xml, por favor necesito mucha ayuda con esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que me aparece con cualquiera de las 2 maneras, me dice que el erro siempre esta al instancias al soapClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el consumo del servicio SOAP, debes tener una direccion que es donde esta el documento WSDL(documento descriptivo del servicio).

http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL

Puedes colocar esa liga en esta pagina, donde te mostrara los metodos expuestos, y los parametros que ocupa el metodo.

http://soapclient.com/soapTest.html

La forma de hacer el llama en php es mediante SoapClient(debes tener la extension php-soap instalada).

```
$call = "Add";
$soapClient = new \SoapClient("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL");
print_r($soapClient->$call(['intA' => 5, 'intB' => 5])->AddResult);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

---

Supongo tendras los accesos? Lo que el wsdl te require para poder visualizarlo se llama Basic Auth.

Puedes intentar de esta forma.

```
$options = array(
 'login' => $username,
 'password' => $password,
);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

o de esta otra forma

```
stream_context_create([ 'ssl' => [ // set some SSL/TLS specific options 
'verify_peer' => false, 
'verify_peer_name' => false, 
'allow_self_signed' => true, 
'header' => array( "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("user:pass"), ) ] ]);
```

[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219463/wsdl-to-php-with-basic-auth#22768683)

Comment: Gracias Hammerfall, me ayudo mucho tu aclaración, ahora funciona mi llamada a soap, pero solo me queda un problema, al llamar el servicio me aparece un error como este: SoapClient::SoapClient  :failed to open stream: HTTP request failed, que quiere decir ese erro, me falto aclarar tambien que este SOAP requiere credenciales de autenticacion para poder consumir su data, login y password, las credenciales se agregan en la instancia del nuevo SoapClient ?

Comment: Dependiendo de como se debe autenticar, lo mas probable es que vaya dentro de los parametros, cual es la liga de tu WSDL? tienes alguna documentacion de ese servicio?

Comment: Si, tengo documentacion de ese servicio, puedo mostrar como esta estructurado el xml de envio y me dices si es que aparece alli lo de autenticacion.

Comment: Claro. Podemos revisarlo

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura del xml del servicio, como no he trabajado tanto con SOAP, no se mucho de los xml, por favor necesito mucha ayuda con esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que me aparece con cualquiera de las 2 maneras, me dice que el erro siempre esta al instancias al soapClient.

Comment: Puedes pegar la liga del WSDL

Comment: O tienes algun documento(pdf o doc) donde te vaya dando instrucciones?

Comment: https://ws.aminerals.cl/RMES/ProxyServices/db_RMES_JIGSAW?wsdl

Comment: Modifique la respuesta, checa si te sirve una de esas dos formas

Comment: Tambien modifique la respuesta y agregue una imagen del erro que me da por network

Comment: ya lo cambie, gracias por decírmelo, soy muy nuevo en la comunidad y aun cometo errores al publicar, gracias @BetaM.